# How can I match phase voltage between a transformer primary and secondary?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transformer, adc, mains, phase-shift

I am trying to make a circuit to transform 240VAC, split-phase to a 0 to 5V waveform for an Arduino ADC so I can measure the mains *voltage*. I have read this question ([How to measure line voltage (220V) with an arduino?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/330674/how-to-measure-line-voltage-220v-with-an-arduino)), which describes very well how to use a transformer to isolate the circuit from mains voltage and bias the transformer secondary voltage so it's always positive (relative to ground).

Simulating this circuit, however, I found that the transformer causes the line voltage and current to be out of phase (as expected for an inductor). I am trying to ensure that my measurement system has a minimal impact on the mains voltage and current, so I wanted to correct the transformer primary power factor so voltage and current are in phase. To do this, I created [the following circuit](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2045%205%2050%0Av%20192%20272%20192%20176%200%201%2060%20170%200%200%200.5%0AT%20240%20176%20336%20272%200%204%200.0435%20-0.08208644742932183%20-2.9544509200229996e-18%200.999%0Ar%20192%20176%20240%20176%200%201500%0Ac%20240%20272%20192%20272%200%200.0000018%20115.09194208987903%0Ao%200%2064%200%2020487%20320%200.2%200%202%200%203%0A):

[image: Power Factor Corrected]

This circuit assumes the primary inductance is 4H, but with the transformer I'd like to use, I can't find its inductance in the [datasheet](http://catalog.triadmagnetics.com/Asset/FS10-110-C2.pdf).

However, when I [add the remainder of the secondary side](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2045%205%2050%0Av%20112%20272%20112%20176%200%201%2060%20170%200%200%200.5%0AT%20160%20176%20256%20272%200%204%200.0435%20-0.08360145712158337%20-0.001574032868710478%200.999%0Ar%20112%20176%20160%20176%200%201500%0Ac%20160%20272%20112%20272%200%200.0000018%20-112.47703396215724%0AR%20256%20224%20256%20208%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20256%20224%20256%20272%200%201000%0Ar%20256%20272%20256%20320%200%201000%0Ag%20256%20320%20256%20336%200%0Aw%20256%20176%20304%20176%200%0Ac%20304%20272%20304%20320%200%200.000001%202.4817271748175065%0Aw%20256%20320%20304%20320%200%0Aw%20304%20320%20352%20320%200%0Aw%20256%20272%20304%20272%200%0Ar%20304%20272%20304%20224%200%201000%0Ar%20304%20224%20304%20176%200%202200%0Ar%20352%20224%20352%20320%200%20100000%0Aw%20304%20224%20352%20224%200%0Ao%200%2064%200%2020487%20320%200.2%200%202%200%203%0Ao%2015%2064%200%2020738%205%200.1%201%202%2015%203%0Ao%200%2064%200%2020678%203.1999999999999996e-14%201e-17%202%202%2015%200%0A), there is a 90° phase shift in the voltage.

[image: Phase Shift in Output]

Here, the second scope is the voltage across the 100kΩ resistor (representing the ADC input). The third scope is an XY-plot with the mains voltage on the x-axis and the ADC input voltage on the y-axis.

I attempted to fix this [with another capacitor](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2045%205%2050%0Av%20112%20272%20112%20176%200%201%2060%20170%200%200%200.5%0AT%20160%20176%20256%20272%200%204%200.0435%20-0.0045205156109541025%200.002907095641037744%200.999%0Ar%20112%20176%20160%20176%200%201500%0Ac%20160%20272%20112%20272%200%200.0000018%20166.64954433474293%0AR%20256%20224%20256%20208%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20256%20224%20256%20272%200%201000%0Ar%20256%20272%20256%20320%200%201000%0Ag%20256%20320%20256%20336%200%0Aw%20256%20176%20304%20176%200%0Ac%20304%20272%20304%20320%200%200.000001%203.4480707406916906%0Aw%20256%20320%20304%20320%200%0Aw%20304%20320%20352%20320%200%0Aw%20256%20272%20304%20272%200%0Ar%20304%20272%20304%20224%200%201000%0Ar%20304%20224%20304%20176%200%202200%0Ar%20400%20224%20400%20320%200%20100000%0Aw%20304%20224%20352%20224%200%0Ac%20352%20224%20352%20320%200%200.000027000000000000002%202.4324711360221527%0Aw%20352%20224%20400%20224%200%0Aw%20352%20320%20400%20320%200%0Ao%200%2064%200%2020487%20320%200.2%200%202%200%203%0Ao%2015%2064%200%2020738%205%200.1%201%202%2015%203%0Ao%200%2064%200%2020678%203.2e-30%201e-33%202%202%2015%200%0A) to induce a 90° phase shift, but I run into a problem where the larger the capacitor is, the closer to output phase is to the input phase, but the gain decreased. Conversely, a smaller capacitor increases my gain, but corrects the phase shift less.

[image: First Attempt to Phase Correct]

It make sense that the gain decreases since the capacitor changes the impedance of the voltage divider, but also changes the impedance of the entire secondary side.

Because of this, I thought about adding an op amp to buffer the stages, but now this is getting more complicated than I can easily design. Ultimately, I need to do three things to the secondary side in order to have the correct input to the ADC:

1. Scale the peak-to-peak voltage to ~5V
2. Add a DC offset of ~2.5V so the output voltage swings from 0 to 5V
3. Phase correct the output voltage so its voltage is no longer leading the mains voltage.

I can use the op amp to both scale the voltage swing and add a DC offset, but I wasn't able to decouple the gain/scaling from the phase correction. I even tried a circuit that [buffered the output twice](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2049%205%2043%0Av%20-48%20224%20-48%20112%200%201%2060%20180%200%200%200.5%0Ac%200%20112%2048%20112%200%200.0000018%20-143.3041705045682%0Ar%20-48%20112%200%20112%200%201500%0Aw%2048%20208%2048%20224%200%0AT%2048%20112%20144%20208%200%204%200.0435%200.07024253639618525%20-0.0001602851952442932%200.999%0Ag%20528%20224%20544%20224%200%0Ar%20528%20144%20528%20224%200%20100000%0Ar%20144%20112%20144%20208%200%20100000%0Ar%20144%20240%20144%20336%200%20100000%0Ar%20528%20304%20528%20224%200%20100000%0AT%2048%20240%20144%20336%200%204%200.0435%200.06243781012994388%20-0.00014247568701883194%200.999%0Aw%2048%20224%20-48%20224%200%0Ar%20-48%20336%200%20336%200%201500%0Ac%200%20336%2048%20336%200%200.0000018%20127.38148489295223%0Av%20-48%20336%20-48%20224%200%201%2060%20160%200%200%200.5%0Ag%20-48%20224%20-64%20224%200%0Ar%20-128%20112%20-128%20336%200%20100000%0Aw%20-48%20112%20-128%20112%200%0Aw%20-48%20336%20-128%20336%200%0Aw%2048%20224%2048%20240%200%0Ar%20320%20336%20240%20336%200%2010000%0Aw%20320%20288%20320%20336%200%0Aw%20240%20304%20240%20336%200%0Aw%20240%20240%20240%20272%200%0Ar%20144%20240%20240%20240%200%2033000%0Ar%20240%20240%20320%20240%200%2010000%0Ar%20144%20336%20240%20336%200%2033000%0Aa%20240%20288%20320%20288%209%2015%20-15%201000000%203.3582425658494333%203.3582847311224033%20100000%0AR%20320%20240%20352%20240%200%200%2040%202.5%200%200%200.5%0Ac%20400%20224%20400%20288%200%200.000042999999999999995%20-2.947376189046293%0Ar%20400%20288%20320%20288%200%20220%0Ar%20400%20160%20320%20160%200%20220%0Ac%20400%20224%20400%20160%200%200.000042999999999999995%20-3.0033022845906707%0AR%20320%20112%20352%20112%200%200%2040%202.5%200%200%200.5%0Aa%20240%20160%20320%20160%209%2015%20-15%201000000%203.4655264850186454%203.465570795991456%20100000%0Ar%20144%20208%20240%20208%200%2033000%0Ar%20240%20112%20320%20112%200%2010000%0Ar%20144%20112%20240%20112%200%2033000%0Aw%20240%20112%20240%20144%200%0Aw%20240%20176%20240%20208%200%0Aw%20320%20160%20320%20208%200%0Ar%20320%20208%20240%20208%200%2010000%0Aa%20448%20144%20528%20144%208%205%200%201000000%203.003258664020102%203.0033022845906707%20100000%0Aw%20528%20144%20528%2096%200%0Aw%20448%20128%20448%2096%200%0Aw%20448%20288%20400%20288%200%0Aw%20448%20160%20400%20160%200%0Aa%20448%20304%20528%20304%209%2015%20-15%201000000%202.9473346376647%202.947376189046293%20100000%0Ar%20528%2096%20448%2096%200%202700%0Ar%20448%20352%20528%20352%200%202700%0Aw%20528%20304%20528%20352%200%0Aw%20448%20320%20448%20352%200%0Ar%20448%2096%20400%2096%200%201000%0Ar%20448%20352%20400%20352%200%201000%0Aw%20528%20224%20400%20224%200%0AR%20400%2096%20368%2096%200%200%2040%202.5%200%200%200.5%0AR%20400%20352%20368%20352%200%200%2040%202.5%200%200%200.5%0Ao%2016%2064%200%2020486%20320%200.003125%200%202%2016%203%0Ao%200%2064%200%2020487%20160%200.1%200%202%200%203%0Ao%2014%2064%200%2020487%20160%200.1%200%202%2014%203%0Ao%207%2064%200%2020738%2010%200.000390625%201%202%207%203%0Ao%208%2064%200%2020738%2010%200.0001953125%201%202%208%203%0Ao%206%2064%200%204354%205%200.0001953125%202%202%206%203%0Ao%209%2064%200%204354%205%200.00009765625%202%202%209%203%0Ao%206%2064%200%2020678%203.1999999999999996e-14%205e-18%203%202%200%200%0Ao%209%2064%200%2020678%201.5999999999999998e-14%205e-18%203%202%2014%200%0A), but still had problems.

How can I accomplish my three goals for conditioning the ADC signal?

Comment: Do you have some strong desire to do the isolation with a transformer, or would you be open to using some form of isolator? There are ways to compensate the nonlinearity of optoisolators with a feedback loop.

Comment: @Hearth I've only ever thought of optos for digital signals, but I guess that's because of the phototransistor non-linearity you mention. It sounds like that might be more complicated and I still need a way to reduce the mains voltage to power an opto. If it's easier though, I'd definitely consider it

Comment: Of course there's also always the option of an isolation amplifier as well, or digitizing the signal with an ADC and then sending it across a digital isolator.

Comment: All of that, though, completely skips over the fact that you _know_ what your circuit is, and you can do the reverse of it in software if you need to. A phase correction isn't that complicated, surely?

Comment: @Hearth You mean phase correcting in software isn't complicated? That is true. At the same time, if I just wish away my problems with software, I won't learn how to design good hardware. I'd prefer to minimize computational load if possible, so a hardware solution would be nice.

Comment: You add a capacitor on the primary side to fix a phase shift that happens when there's no load on the secondary side. Have you verified that after you include a load on the secondary side you still get current and voltage in phase on the primary side with this "fix" in place?

Comment: @ThePhoton The secondary doesn't really get loaded much... I could try artificially loading the secondary to see if that pulls the power factor to unity on the primary. The trouble is I don't know the inductance of the transformer I'd like to use (not in datasheet), so I don't know how to simulate an appropriate load. Could you either look at the datasheet to see if you can get more info or provide info on sizing the load based on the primary's inductance?

Comment: How much phase error do you get just using the transformer on its own directly connected across the AC supply?

Comment: Unfortunately, transformer vendors don't usually provide that information. But you're right that you're using this one well below its rating. Probably you can find a smaller and cheaper transformer that will work better in this application.

Comment: @Andyaka Just using the transformer (with a lightly loaded secondary), voltage and current are 90° out of phase. The secondary voltage, however, is in phase with the primary voltage.

Comment: Then you haven't chosen a correct value burden resistor for your CT. Your VT isn't at fault it seems.

Comment: @ThePhoton Given how small this transformer is, I'm finding it difficult to find anything smaller... I tried your suggestion of loading the secondary, and it pulls the primary voltage and current in phase with each other, but they're always phase shifted by some amount. Using a capacitor on the primary pretty much ensures a high power factor when lightly loaded.

Comment: @Andyaka What CT? Unless I'm mistaking your terminology, I'm trying to transform voltage, not measure current (which I'm doing in a separate application, but that circuit is easier). Also, this is why I'm asking this question. I am asking for assistance in designing this so I have a high power factor on the primary and a signal going to my ADC that is in phase with the primary voltage.

Comment: @HariGanti, maybe something like [this](https://productfinder.pulseeng.com/doc_type/WEB301/doc_num/P795/doc_part/P795.pdf)?

Comment: @ThePhoton I was just thinking it would be nice to scale the voltage on the mains-side and then isolate it, so this type of transformer would be perfect. My only concern it its power factor since that's the motivation that caused this problem in the first place

Comment: With the transformer "hidden" from the mains input behind a 50-100k resistor, I wouldn't expect there to be much power factor impact. But maybe your requirements are really extreme.

Comment: @ThePhoton I expect the impact to truly be minimal, but (like before), it's really a difference of doing it the "easy" way, which is higher-power, higher distortion, phase shifted, etc. vs trying to design better. In the end, I don't really care if the µC is isolated from mains voltage or not because none of this will have human contact, but I'd like to see if I can implement a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

With no load (or a very light load) on the secondary, the primary current will lag the primary voltage by 90 degrees. This is because the primary inductance dominates and, because it is an inductor, it will take a current that is largely 90 degrees lagging the applied voltage. Nothing strange happening here. This is transformer physics.

The output voltage will be in phase with the input voltage because the secondary induced voltage is proportional to the rate of change of primary magnetization current and, this therefore adds another 90 degrees to the current waveform.

Comment: This all makes sense, and certainly explains why adding a capacitor to the primary will correct the lag for a lightly-loaded secondary, but is there a way to modify the circuit to achieve: 1) Near-unity power factor for the primary, 2) A 0-5V output voltage, and 3) Zero phase shift between the primary and secondary voltage?

Comment: I think the problem for anyone reading this question is that it didn't become clear what you were doing until you last previous comment! Previously it seemed you were using a CT (current transformer) to measure power!

Comment: It did? I apologize. I thought it was clear from the linked question. I'll edit my question to state that I am trying to measure voltage, not current.