# How can I measure voltage up to 120V in an Arduino?

Tags: arduino, voltage, resistors, resistance, voltage-measurement

I'm a beginner in electronics world, I've developed things before but not so sofisticated. Now I have to create a prototype and I need to measure voltages up to 120V. I've seen there are sensors that can do this job but they're only capable to measure 5-25V. Is there any way I can transform voltage from 5-120V to 5-25? I need to know when there's a change in voltage. Or any other idea that could help me?
I explain: my controller will have storaged the voltage when there's a device plugged-in and it's working, I need to find the way to measure this voltage so I'll be able to storage it dynamicly and compare this storaged value to the actual so I'll know when the device plugged-in is ON or OFF.
I appreciate your attention, thanks.

Comment: [Start by looking up any of the approximately 5 million other questions about this very thing.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/330674/how-to-measure-line-voltage-220v-with-an-arduino?rq=1)

Comment: @JRE thanks! And sorry about that.